# SQL query for listing values based on a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the following columns member_id, status and created_at (timestamp) and i want to extract the latest status for each member_id based on the timestamp value.

| member_id | status | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ON | 1641862225 |
| 1 | OFF | 1641862272 |
| 2 | OFF | 1641862397 |
| 3 | OFF | 1641862401 |
| 3 | ON | 1641862402 |

[Source: Raw data image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZqxj.png)

So, my ideal query result would be like this:

| member_id | status | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | OFF | 1641862272 |
| 2 | OFF | 1641862397 |
| 3 | ON | 1641862402 |

[Expected query results image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lptj5.png)

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: i'm using mysql

Comment: @jo1242 what version of mysql?

Comment: the version i'm using is 8.0

Answer (score 1):

My go to process for doing things like that is to assign a row number to each data and get row number 1 depending on the partition and sorting.

For mysql, this is only available starting mysql 8

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY member_id ORDER BY created_at DESC) as row_num, 
member_id, status, created_at FROM table
```

This will generate something like this.

| row_num | member_id | status | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | OFF | 1641862272 |
| 2 | 1 | ON | 1641862225 |
| 1 | 2 | OFF | 1641862397 |
| 1 | 3 | ON | 1641862402 |
| 2 | 3 | OFF | 1641862401 |

Then you use that as a sub query and get the rows where `row_num = 1`

```
SELECT member_id, status, created_at FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY member_id ORDER BY created_at DESC) as row_num, 
    member_id, status, created_at FROM table
) a WHERE row_num = 1
```

Comment: That's how I would do it in MS SQL, good news if MySQL has finally caught up.

Answer (score 0):

> [MySQL has support for Window Function](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/) since v8.0. the solution from [crimson589](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70660753/1690217) is preferred for v8+, this solution applies for earlier versions of MySQL or if you need an alternate solution to window queries.

After grouping by `member_id` we can either join back into the original set to gain the corresponding `status` value to the `MAX(created_at)`

```
SELECT ByMember.member_id
, status.status
, ByMember.created_at
FROM (
  SELECT member_id, max(created_at) as created_at
  FROM MemberStatus
  GROUP BY member_id
  ) ByMember
JOIN MemberStatus status ON ByMember.member_id = status.member_id AND ByMember.created_at = status.created_at;
```

Or you could use a sub query instead of the join:

```
SELECT ByMember.member_id
, (SELECT status.status FROM MemberStatus status WHERE ByMember.member_id = status.member_id AND ByMember.created_at = status.created_at) as status
, ByMember.created_at
FROM (
  SELECT member_id, max(created_at) as created_at
  FROM MemberStatus
  GROUP BY member_id
  ) ByMember
```

The `JOIN` based solution allows you to query additional columns from the original set instead of having multiple sub-queries. I would almost always advocate for the `JOIN` solution, but sometimes the sub-query is simpler to maintain.

I've setup a fiddle to compare these options: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0edb931/11

Answer (score -1):

You can group by `member_id` and max of `created_at`, then a self join with `member_id` and `created_at` will give you the latest status.